# Remove files of all kinds in a shortcut

Tags: bash

I'd like to remove files of `.md` `.txt` `.py` etc and leave exclusively the directory.

Test with ls to display all the directories

```
    $ ls -d
    .
```

> ```
> -d      Directories are listed as plain files (not searched recursively).
> ```

and

```
    $ ls -f
    .         ..        bar.txt a.txt, foo.md zoo bar foo
```

It print files and dirs in unsorted order.

How could remove just files.

Comment: You may also want to remove .pyc fies, you can just toss it into the file extension check below.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Full command

```
find . -type f -maxdepth 1 | grep "\.[txt|md|py]" | xargs rm -f {} \;
```

Files the files in the current directory

```
find . -type f -maxdepth 1
```

pipe that to grep, searching for file extensions on an OR fashion in []

```
| grep "\.[txt|md|py]"
```

pipe the grep output to xargs which accepts to ehe content from grep and executes rm -f on each argument passed

```
| xargs rm -f {} \;

$ touch foo.bar
$ find . -type f -maxdepth 1 | grep "\.[txt|md|py]"
./testing.txt
./test.py
./readme.md
$ find . -type f -maxdepth 1 | grep "\.[txt|md|py]" | xargs rm -f {} \;
$ ls -alh
total 0
drwxr-xr-x   6 tcrowder  staff   192B Apr  8 23:02 .
drwxr-xr-x   3 tcrowder  staff    96B Apr  4 22:15 ..
drwxr-xr-x  11 tcrowder  staff   352B Apr  4 22:23 .git
drwxr-xr-x   7 tcrowder  staff   224B Apr  4 22:23 .idea
-rw-r--r--   1 tcrowder  staff     0B Apr  8 23:01 foo.bar
$
```

Comment: `\.[txt|md|py]` match on every string which contains a dot followed by a `t` or `x` or `m` or `d` or `p` or `y` or `|`.

Comment: Thank both of you very much. @Cyrus

Comment: `grep "\.[txt|md|py]"` matches ./temp.py, ./temp.dm, ./temp.tp.php

Comment: `grep -E "\.(txt|md|py)"`  matches ./temp.py

Answer (score 1):

You know `rm` command?

```
rm *.txt *.md *.py
```